# Wordpress install in root and in subfolder + two domains

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

God, this little problem drives me crazy and I really hope that you'll help me how to figure it out.

I searched over all previous threads and in the codex of wordpress, didn't find my exact problem.
This is it :
I've one host with a wordpress installed at the root. I've one domain pointing it. Everything is fine.
I've need now a second install of wordpress, that i've installed in a subfolder. I've a second domain, linked to this subdfoler.

Like this :

- root > domain.net
- root/subfolder > anotherdomain.net

If I let the "site url" setting and the "wordpress url" setting with "domain.net/subfolder", this is OK, I can access to my second site and all permalinks work.

But if I edit my site url/wordpress url in "anotherdomain.net" it renders the "domain.net" homepage without style...

I'm sure this is a question of HTACCESS but I can't find how to properly write it...

Thanks for your answers !

(sorry for my english, not my mother tongue)

EDIT : Here are .htaccess (at this state, I let them in order to access subfolder via domain.net/subfolder)

root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

root/subfolder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the config were good, the problem was with my host provider.

For the record, the htaccess for the site in the subfolder, when everything is ok :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And the site and wordpress urls pointing to the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

HTACCESS would be my first guess too, but another thought occurred to me: have you made sure that you are installing the two sites in two distinct SQL databases?

Assuming this is not the problem, is there any way you paste your htaccess files, so I can see if there is an issue in them?

Comment: Yep, two distinct databases, and I've edited my question with htaccess files. Thanks !

Comment: Check your wp-config.php files, especially in the subfolder install. It dawned on me after reading this again that it could be a CONTENT DIR problem: your second install could be looking in the wrong folder for content (i.e. the header.php, style.css, etc).